# Vim jump between words and stop at end of line

Tags: cursor-movement, gvim, cursor-motions, normal-mode

In normal mode, <kbd>b</kbd> and <kbd>w</kbd> are jumping between words,

and I would like to stop at the end of line.

For example:

The cursor is right over here

[image]

When I press <kbd>w</kbd>, what I expect is

[image]

Instead, the cursor jump to beginning of next line.

Should I `set iskeyword` or something? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Use <kbd>e</kbd> key - it moves cursor to the `end` of a word-object. See `:h word-motions` for more movement keys.

Comment: Is there a way just make 'w' stop at the end of the line? 'e' does not stop in an empty line.

Comment: That would probably require custom non-trivial function. Personally I think that it's better to learn how to use motions as they are, because later you will forget that you have custom motion mapping and something will relay on it and it won't work just for you - and it's really hard to change habits. But maybe you're looking for `$`? This will jump to the end of current line.

Comment: I know `e` and `$`, but I would like to use `w` all the way.

Comment: Then @statox's answer is what you need.

Answer (score 4):

While I deeply agree with @grodzik comment (*it's better to learn how to use motions as they are, because later you will forget that you have custom motion mapping*) here is a custom funciton and mapping to do what you want:

```
" Override w motion
function! MyWMotion()
    " Save the initial position
    let initialLine=line('.')

    " Execute the builtin word motion and get the new position
    normal! w
    let newLine=line('.')

    " If the line as changed go back to the previous line
    if initialLine != newLine
        normal k$
    endif
endfunction

" Override b motion
function! MyBMotion()
    " Save the initial position
    let initialLine=line('.')

    " Execute the builtin word motion and get the new position
    normal! b
    let newLine=line('.')

    " If the line as changed go back to the previous line
    if initialLine != newLine
        normal j^
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> w :call MyWMotion()<CR>
nnoremap <silent> b :call MyBMotion()<CR>
```

I haven't tested it extensively so maybe some corner cases will create problems but that should be a good start.

Also as I mentioned before this code is only to show that it is possible to do that I wouldn't recommend to use it.